# Pass the status to resize function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D5yXF/) -

1. (landing) Check browser size > Change polygon size
2. Click button > Change polygon size (smaller)
3. Resize browser > Change polygon size
4. Resize browser > Check if already click button to smaller mode before > Change polygon size to smaller

I'm stuck in 4. I can't figure how to pass the before status to after resize. It will calculate again.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

`Demo`

```
$(function(){
var adivide=0;
var winwid = $(window).width();
function setadivide(){  
    winwid = $(window).width(); 
    if(winwid > 800){
        adivide = 8;
    }
    else{
        adivide = 4;
    }
    console.log(adivide);
};
setadivide();

var awidth;
function acal(){
    awidth = parseInt( winwid / adivide);
};
acal();
function setawidth(){
    $('.a').css({width: awidth, height: awidth});
};
setawidth();

//****** button
//set btn visibility
function btnvis(){
    switch(adivide){
        case 4:
            $('.plus').show();
            $('.minus').hide();
        break;
        case 8:
            $('.plus').show();
            $('.minus').hide();
        break;
    }
};
btnvis();
//click btn update adivide and set btn visibility
function btnclick(){
    $('.plus').click(function(){
        switch(adivide){
            case 4:
                adivide = adivide -2;
                console.log(adivide);
                acal();
                setawidth();
                $('.plus').hide();
                $('.minus').show();
            break;
            case 8:
                adivide = adivide - 2;
                console.log(adivide);
                acal();
                setawidth();
                $('.plus').hide();
                $('.minus').show();
            break;
        }
    });
    $('.minus').click(function(){
        switch(adivide){
            case 2:
                adivide = adivide + 2;
                console.log(adivide);
                acal();
                setawidth();
                $('.plus').show();
                $('.minus').hide();
            break;
            case 6:
                adivide = adivide + 2;
                console.log(adivide);
                acal();
                setawidth();
                $('.plus').show();
                $('.minus').hide();
            break;
        }
    });
};
btnclick();
//end button ******
$(window).resize(function(){
    setadivide();
    acal();
    setawidth();
    //****** button
    btnvis();
    //end button ******
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Edited answer)

Modify your setadivide function to take into account current `adivide` value (i.e. current status):

```
function setadivide(){    
    winwid = $(window).width();    
    if(winwid > 800){
        if (adivide == 2)
           adivide = 6;
        else if (adivide != 6)
           adivide = 8;
    }
    else{
        if (adivide == 6)
           adivide = 2;
        else if (adivide != 2)
           adivide = 4;
    }
    console.log(adivide);
};
```

[Modified demo](http://jsfiddle.net/29hFt/4/)

Comment: Thanks for reply! but if remove `setadivide()`, then the polygon can't change size after browser resize.

Comment: @user1775888 I have edited the answer, now the demo should work as requested.